Being able to stop pytest execution but providing repot when some conditions are reached
I'm in the need of some quite strange use case. I have a bunch of pytest tests running, which are doing their stuff. Some of them are changing an environment.
These tests are daily running. And I can access to their reports. But I was thinking if it's possible to stop test execution when some tests are failing in order to keep env in "failure" to be able to debug what is wrong.
My test plan installs a version in an environment and runs a set of tests before changing that version to another one, it runs another set of tests and finally changes version again to run another set of tests.
Something like

Version 1
Block A of tests
Version 2
Block B of tests
Version 3
Block C of tests

After block A I would like to check if there were some failure in tests and if that is the case stop rest of test execution (steps 3 to 6) and generate a report. Same behaviour after block B (not running steps 5 and 6) and block C (this should be easiest due to regular test execution can do, just controlling not cleaning up the environment in teardown)
I know it looks strange but I think it should be possible based in report itself. At the end, pytest has to control how tests are going and keeping info of what happened.
I've seen this as a possible entry point, but couldn't figure out how to reach my needs.
Thanks a lot for reading and your help.

Do you mean -x (stop at the first failing test)?

Not exactly due to every block is isolated, I mean. In block A I can have 10 tests, which are independent. One could fail and others no, but env remains the same. Running them are not going to affect environment. So, it's better if I could stop in case of one or more failures in every block.
But I will study that -x , just in case I could use it as partial solution. Thanks!!!

I think that not being 100% accurate with my needs, what @AKX suggested joined to pytest-timeout plugin and controlling teardown. It can be a working solution to my needs. Will try.
Thanks again for your help AKX
